# Components won't rerender after change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm building a basic todo app using three components: **CreateTodo**, **TodoList** and **TodoItem**. However, whenever I type a new task and click the button, **TodoList** doesn't rerender until I perform some kind of change on the text input. Also, after setting a task as completed, the **TodoItem** won't rerender with the new styles unless I refresh the page. I'm new to reactjs, so any comments on those bugs would be very helpful. Here are the components:

CreateTodo:

```
function CreateTodo() {
    
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState({title: "", done: false});
    const [todoArr, setTodoArr] = useState([]);

    const onChange = (event) => {
        let {value} = event.target;
        let obj = {};
        obj["title"] = value;
        obj["done"] = false;
        setTodo(obj);
    }

    const createTodo = (event) => {
        const {name} = event.target;
        if(event.key === "Enter" || name === "addTodo"){
            if(todo.title !== ""){
                todoArr.unshift(todo);
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todoArr));
            }else{
                swal("Oops", "Please write todo first", "error");
            }
        }
    }

    const completeTodo = (i) => {
        if(todoArr[i]["done"] !== true){
            todoArr[i]["done"] = true;
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoArr));
            setTodoArr(todoArr);
            swal("Good job!", "Todo Completed", "success");
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className = "card">
                <div className = "card-header">
                    
                </div>
                <div className = "card-body">
                    <h5 className = "card-title">Add a new Todo</h5>
                    <form className = 'form-inline justify-content-center'>
                        <input type = 'text' className = 'form-control' placeholder = 'New Todo' onKeyPress = {createTodo} onChange = {onChange} value = {todo.title}/>
                        <button type = "button" name = "addTodo" className = "btn btn-primary" onClick = {createTodo}>Add Todo</button>
                    </form>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <TodoList todoArr = {todoArr} completeTodo = {completeTodo} />
        </>
    );
}
```

TodoList:

```
function TodoList(props) {
    const {completeTodo} = props;
    let todoArr = props.todoArr.length > 0 ? props.todoArr : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className = "list-group list-group-flush">
                {todoArr && todoArr.length > 0 ? 
                todoArr.map((el,i) => (
                    <TodoItem key = {el.title} text = {el.title} index = {i} completeTodo = {props.completeTodo} done = {el["done"]} />
                )): null
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

TodoItem:

```
function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <li className = 'list-group-item'>
            <div className = {props.done ? "line-through" : null}>{props.text}</div>
            <span className = 'icons'>
                <i className = {`fa fa-check-circle fa-2x pointer ${props.done ? "yellowgreen" : "skyblue"}`} aria-hidden="true" onClick = {()=>props.completeTodo(props.index)}></i>
                <i className ="fa fa-trash fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `createTodo` function never calls `setTodoArr`. Mutating the array won't inform React that the value changed. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @FelixKling I tried adding `setTodoArr(todoArr);` after mutating the array, but the problems  I described didn't go away.

Comment: What if you do `todoArr = [todo, ...todoArr]; setTodoArr(todoArr);` instead of calling `unshift`?

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that solved the problem of TodoList not rendering on time, but there are some other weird stuff going on. After every reload of the page, when I try to add a todo, the LocalStorage automatically deletes the rest. Also, some styles that I add in TodoItem with react do not show until page is reloaded.